# insert data from table associated with other

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL database I have 1 table:

```
 Client (id, name, adress, city)
```

I want to Create multiple adresses for 1 client, so I created new table

```
 Adresse (id, id_client, adress, city)
```

I want to populate adress table with data imported from client table

for exemple i have data

```
  |  id | name |adress| city  |
  |-----|------|------|-------|
  |  1  | c1   | ad1  |paris  |
  |  2  | c2   | ad2  |nice   |
```

i want my new table adress populated with data from client table juste like this

```
   | id | id_client|adress|city  |
   |----|----------|------|------|
   | 1  | 1        | ad1  |paris |
   | 2  | 2        | ad2  |nice  |
```

I googled a lot and didn't find the solution

Comment: you want to only import one table data to another isn't it/

Comment: It sounds like you should be able to just use "INSERT INTO addresse (id_client,name,adress,city) SELECT id,name,adress,city FROM client;" - then use something like Gagantous's query to look the data up, but I might not be understanding the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i understood you want to import data from one table to another so you can do it below query

```
insert into adresse select * from client;
```

Comment: the problem is the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple 
insert into adresse select * from client;
sorry guys i'm so stupid

Comment: i have already given that answer above please mark it as correct